# Undefined index: data error message

Tags: php, post

I am getting a variable from a form called 'data' then I am coping the value of it into variable called $view
`$view=$_POST['data'];`
I am using the variable $view to determine the receiver of the message and insert it into the database.
Everything is going fine with me and the value is being inserted into the database but I am still getting this error message from the server **Undefined index: data**.
How can I get rid of that message and why it is showing while the code is working fine?

Comment: Can you show examples of your code? Cheers.

Comment: Mr @RossWilson I just did that on my question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The post variable `data` doesn't exist. You can set the `$view` variable such as:

`$view = !empty($_POST['data']) ? $_POST['data'] : false;`

Comment: Because PHP is throwing a notice - not an error. It's basically for developers saying "Hey, you... you're setting this variable but from a source of [nothing]"

Comment: good answer now the code is working with no error message but can I get a little explanation about what you did? and what was that code?

Comment: Using ternary operator assignment, I'm setting `$view` based on the conditional `!empty($_POST['data'])`. If it's `true`, we use `$_POST['data']`. If it's false, we set it to `false`. This can be expressed (in a longer format): `if(!empty($_POST['data'])) { $view = $_POST['data']; } else { $view = false; }` - see how smaller it is?